# Navigation bar not positioning at the top of page

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have just started learning code and I have managed to solve most problems on my own. However, this one is getting the better of me.

I am trying to get the navigation bar to sit at the top of the page with the text below it but the  element just sits underneath the navigation bar and stops the navigation bar hitting the top of the page.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Many thanks,
Russ

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #404040;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="../Home/Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../About/about.html">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="../Contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1> hello world</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `top:0` on the `fixed` element.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #404040;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav + * {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="../Home/Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../About/about.html">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="../Contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1> hello world</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This does solve the nav bar not being positioned at the top of the page however, the <h1> element still appears underneath the nav bar.

Comment: You must add a "padding-top" on the "body" so that the content is padded exactly with the amount of pixels that the navbar takes (I.e. Its height)

Comment: Thanks Felix and Victor, it is sorted now!